# How accurate are percentage units in css?

Tags: javascript, css, math, cross-browser, percentage

Let's say I have a gallery layout that is generated with javascript. Right now it uses the pixel unit for positioning, sizes etc. The problem with this is that the possible presence of a scrollbar affects how it is rendered. I can detect if there is a scrollbar initially, but if there isn't and the layout itself makes a scrollbar appear the whole thing is off with 20px.

(to solve this) I was thinking to switch to percentage units for widths and left positions, and leave pixels just for heights and top positions.

My questions is, will that be as accurate as pixels? For example. if I want the spacing between images to be exactly 20 pixels, I would divide 20 by the width of my layout container element and get something like 1.112%. Will the left and width properties be just as accurate with these kind of percentage values?

Comment: *"if I want the spacing between images to be exactly 20 pixels"* ... then you probably should use pixels.

Comment: so nobody ever used percentage units here? weird...

Comment: Pixels are fixed-size units, 20px will be 20px. Percentage is a scalable unit, 20% might be whatever depending on font-size or viewport.